# How do I insert a border below text?

Tags: formatting, rules

I want to emulate a feature from a few word processing programs (e.g. Microsoft Word, LibreOffice Writer) where I could (somewhat) arbitrarily insert a bottom border below any text/paragraph. How can I do this in LaTeX?

Edit: Just to clarify, what I want is pretty much a horizontal line across the page just below the text. Like this:

[image: Bottom border]

Comment: By "border", do you mean a horizontal line (since you want it "below" text/paragraph)? If not, post a screen grab from your MS Office/LibreOffice Writer as part of your question, almost like presenting an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Yes, a horizontal line right below the text. I'll add a screengrab just to make sure it's clear.

Comment: Related Question: [End of paragraph with ornament](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11320/end-of-paragraph-with-ornament).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this. Have you tried issuing the command

```
\hrule
```

on a line by itself?

Comment: Didn't realize it was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

With a slight modification from @egreg's answer to [Shift horizontal line to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29574/shift-horizontal-line-to-the-left/29578#29578), the following minimal working example (MWE) provides `\myrule[<thickness>][<gap>][<color>]`, that places a rule of thickness `<thickness>` between paragraphs (default is `1pt`). Additionally, the second optional argument allows you to increase the gap between the line and the preceding/succeeding paragraph (default is `3pt`). Finally, the last optional argument allows you to change the colour of the line to `<color>` (default is `black`). Colour is provided by means of `\color` from the [`xcolor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{1pt} O{3pt} O{black}}{%
  \par\nobreak % don't break a page here
  \kern\the\prevdepth % don't take into account the depth of the preceding line
  \kern#2 % space before the rule
  {\color{#3}\hrule height #1 width\hsize} % the rule
  \kern#2 % space after the rule
  \nointerlineskip % no additional space after the rule
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\myrule

\lipsum[2]

\myrule[10pt][5pt]

\lipsum[3]

\myrule[5pt][5pt][orange]

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach using an `environment`. The advantage of this approach is that you can decorate the content of the environment globally in your preamble. You could combine this idea with Werner's to make the border more colourful.

I have used the `needspace` package to make sure that the `\hrule` doesn't get separated from the last line of the paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}     % needed for sample text
\usepackage{needspace}  % provides the \needspace command
\newenvironment{bottomborder}%
{}  % code to be processed before the environment begins
{\needspace{\baselineskip}\hrule} % code to be processed after the environment ends
\begin{document}

\begin{bottomborder}
\lipsum[1-3] 
\end{bottomborder}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using this approach, you could, for example, add an `\hrule` before the environment begins as well.