# How can I create a macro that does nothing if it appears at the top of a page?

Tags: macros, page-breaking

How can I define a macro that does nothing if it is the first item on a page, but does something (e.g. inserts a rule or a space) if it appears elsewhere?

Something along these lines is discussed in section 28.4.5 of [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/texbytopic), but I don't understand it well enough to customise it.

Comment: Similar question to [Can I make some vertical material disappear if it occurs next to a page break?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/can-i-make-some-vertical-material-disappear-if-it-occurs-next-to-a-page-break) Both Mico's and Werner's answers worked fine in that context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glue disappears at the top of the page; glue is a special case of leaders, that have the same property:

```
\newcommand{\disappearing}{\par % we need to be in vertical mode
  \cleaders\vbox to 24pt{\hrule\vfill\hbox{SOMETHING}\vfill\hrule}%
  \vskip24pt}

\newpage
\disappearing

some text

\disappearing
```

The box will appear only after "some text", not at the top of the page.