# Colored horizontal line between two texts

Tags: color, rules

How I can get color horizontal line between two texts? I am using command `\rule{16cm}{1mm}`. Can any one suggest how to change the color of horizontal line.

Comment: `\textcolor{red}{\rule{16cm}{1mm}}`

Comment: Related: [How do I insert a border below text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30973/5764)

Answer (score 14):

Very simply (don't forget `\noindent` if it's between paragraphs):

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[textwidth = 16cm]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \noindent\textcolor{PaleVioletRed3}{\rule{16cm}{1mm}}

    \lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using \newcommand{\divider}{\vskip1pt\hrule\vskip1pt} , it works. but it gives the black color line. If i changed the color, the space between line and text become more.

Comment: It's normal you get a black rule, since you have no colour command. As for the second sentence I don't know what happening since it's unfinished…

Answer (score 12):

The following example defines `\sepline` that prints a colored line between paragraphs, if the end of the first and the start of the second paragraph are on the same page. The line vanishes at page breaks.

`\sepline` is vertically centered between the paragraphs. If `\parskip` is non-zero, then half of `\parskip` is put before and the other half after the line.

The line can be configured by:

- Length `\seplinewidth`: line width/thickness
- Length `\seplinesep`: additional vertical space around the line
- Color `sepline`: The color for the line, can be changed by `\colorlet` or `\definecolor`.

Full Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[textwidth = 16cm]{geometry}

\newlength{\seplinewidth}
\newlength{\seplinesep}
\setlength{\seplinewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\seplinesep}{2mm}
\colorlet{sepline}{PaleVioletRed3}
\newcommand*{\sepline}{%
  \par
  \vspace{\dimexpr\seplinesep+.5\parskip}%
  \cleaders\vbox{%
    \begingroup % because of color
      \color{sepline}%
      \hrule width\linewidth height\seplinewidth
    \endgroup
  }\vskip\seplinewidth
  \vspace{\dimexpr\seplinesep-.5\parskip}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\sepline
\lipsum[2]
\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}
\sepline
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]