# setheadsepline color in scrartcl

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I am struggling to add a header with a colored headsepline to my header.

I have tried to add a command like this:

```
\setheadsepline{\color{1blue}}
```

But instead of the colored line I got the whole text blue. I know it's probably an easier fix, but I just can't find it. I want to have the same color on the header line, as I have on the Titlepage.

Sample:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}

\usepackage{microtype} %Spacing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{setspace}

%Titlepage
\colorlet{1blue}{RoyalBlue!65}

%NewCommand HRule for Titlepage
\newcommand{\HRule}{\textcolor{1blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5mm}}}

%Header
\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setheadsepline{\color{1blue}}
\ihead{}
\chead{}
%\ohead{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Bilder/krutec-logo-m.png}}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

Minimal example

\end{document}
```

Comment: See question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223275/16550 possible duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\setheadsepline` does not expect a colour but a length as mandatory argument. So your example results in an error message:

> ```
> ./test.tex:32: Argument of \@scr@setline has an extra }.
> <inserted text> 
>                 \par 
> l.32 \setheadsepline{\color{1blue}}
> ```

However, `scrpage2` is obsolete/deprecated. See the warning message produced by `scrpage2`:

> ```
> Package scrpage2 Warning: usage of obsolete package!
> (scrpage2)                Package `scrpage2' is obsolete.
> (scrpage2)                You should not longer use package `scrpage2'.
> (scrpage2)                You should replace usage of package `scrpage2'
> (scrpage2)                by `scrlayer-scrpage' on input line 52.
> ```

or have a look into the `scrpage2` manual, `scrpage2.pdf`, that is titled:

[image: The Obsolete package scrpage2]

and states in the preamble of the first chapter:

[image: recommendation to use scrlayer-scrpage]

Usage of `scrlayer-scrpage` as recommended by the information shown above, with the correct user interface for setting up the colour, which is explained in the KOMA-Script manuals, `scrguien.pdf` or `scrguide.pdf`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}% a4paper is default

% 1st: Load packages
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype} %Spacing
\usepackage{graphicx} % not used by the example
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption} % not used by the exmaple
\usepackage{float} % not used by the example
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% scrpage2 is obsolete
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

% 2nd: Do configuration (using the packages)

\newcommand{\HRule}{\textcolor{1blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5mm}}}% not used by the example
\colorlet{1blue}{RoyalBlue!65}
\urlstyle{same} % not used by the example

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{1blue}}% setting up the colour of element headsepline
\clearpairofpagestyles
%\ohead{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Bilder/krutec-logo-m.png}}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% \pagemark also on plain pages

\begin{document}

Minimal example

\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: left top edge of a page]

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the syntax of `\setheadsepline`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}

\usepackage{microtype} %Spacing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{setspace}

%Titlepage
\colorlet{1blue}{RoyalBlue!65}

%NewCommand HRule for Titlepage
\newcommand{\HRule}{\textcolor{1blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5mm}}}

%Header
\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setheadsepline{0.5mm}[\color{1blue}]
\ihead{}
\chead{}
%\ohead{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Bilder/krutec-logo-m.png}}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

Minimal example

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not use `scrpage2` any longer. It could be removed from KOMA-Script with any future release, because it warns that it is obsolete for almost two years and the official successor is already available for more than six years.

Comment: Thanks. That line works now.

@Schweinebacke What should I use instead? I searched for hours for a way to get a header.

Comment: @Severus15 See my answer I gave 5 minutes before Bernard or the answer to the question Kurt has linked in his comment to your question. And have a look into the KOMA-Script manual. There is a chapter about it.